# Finding an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with $|V| = |E|+1$ that's not a tree

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone help me for this problem:

> Give an example of undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ where $|V|=|E|+1$, but $G$ is not a tree.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a triangle plus an isolated point?

[image: Triangle plus an isolated point]

Comment: please explain more not clear to me the answer

Comment: @leenaadam, a triangle has three vertices and three edges, plus an isolated vertex there are 4 vertices and three edges in the graph.

Answer (score 2):

As @Easy mentioned, you may take cycles $C_n$ and an isolated vertex.

Comment: CW? ${ }$ ${ }$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try a disconnected graph.

Answer (score 1):

For $n \geq 1$, since (a) all $n$-vertex trees have $n-1$ edges, (b) all connected graphs have spanning trees, and (c) disconnected graphs are not trees, we have the following:

*Theorem*: Let $G$ be a graph with $n \geq 1$ vertices and $n-1$ edges.  Then $G$ is a tree if and only if $G$ is connected.